# rmarkdown generated PDF： error in eval object 'mean_list' not found

Tags: r, r-markdown

My code is as follows:

````
## Simulation 5
```{r}
nRuns <- 100
for (i in seq_len(nRuns)) {
  x <- rpois(10, lambda = 10)
  mean_data <- mean(x)
  mean_list <- c(mean_list, mean_data)
}
```
````

When I generated PDF use knit.
It returns this error: `object mean_list not found`.

How can I fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: Seems like you assign `c(mean_list, mean_data)` to `mean_list` without defining `mean_list` in the first place.

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Instead, paste the code into the question itself and format it as a code block.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved this problem by defining mean_list as a global variable!